# Error is loading the jars

Tags: java, classpath, ejb

i`m getting NoClassDefintion found error in my application even though i had the associated jars in my lin folder of my ear the error is

`java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is:
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/rave/web/ui/model/Option`

Note i had added the same user library to my eclipse its not showing any compilation error this error is only at runtime ......!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used EJBs for a while but I seem to remember having to set up the classpath differently for EJBs. I think you have to set it in the manifest.mf file in the EJB jar.

A quick Google turns up [this thread](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v4r0/topic/com.ibm.support.was40.doc/html/Classloader/swg21052375.html), suggesting you need to put:

`Class-Path: jar1.jar, jar2.jar`

In your manifest.mf file.

You might also find [this page](http://edocs.bea.com/wls/docs70/programming/classloading.html) (scroll right down to the bottom) and [this one](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#JAR) (search for "Class-Path") helpful.